# For which value of $k$ is the following matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

\begin{pmatrix}7&k\\ \:0&7\end{pmatrix}

I could not figure out how to derive the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix above because of the letter $k$. How am I supposed to deal with a value in terms of $k$? And how would I be able to find out if the matrix is diagonalizable or not through that?

Comment: You should be able to find the eigenvalues, k will not be involved for this. Then, compare algebraic multiplicity with geometric multiplicity.

Comment: I see. But how will I be able to find the value of k by comparing the algebraic and geometric multiplicities?

Comment: First start with the eigenvalues of this matrix.

Comment: Just try and tell us what you get.

Comment: OK. So I believe the eigenvalue is 7 with algebraic multiplicity of 2. Is this correct? If so, how can I find the geometric multiplicity and value of k? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal A$ be the matrix \begin{pmatrix}7&k\\ \:0&7\end{pmatrix}

The characteristic polynomial of $\mathcal A$ is $p(\lambda)=(7-\lambda)^2$.

Observe that $ (\mathcal A - 7\mathcal Id)(x,y) = (0,0) \iff ky=0$. Clearly if $k=0$ $\mathcal A$ is diagonalizable. If $k \ne 0$ then $ky = 0 \iff y=0$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Oh I see. So the matrix is only diagonalizable for k = 0?

Comment: How you conclude that?

Comment: Because if k = 0, then y does not equal 0? And for the matrix to be diagonalizable, y must not be 0?

Comment: @sktsasus What does the constraint $y=0$ tell you about the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $7$?

Comment: That the geometric multiplicity is not 0?

Comment: @sktsasus The geometric multiplicity is 1. (The eigenvectors are exactly the nonzero multiples of $(1\ 0)^T$.) What can you conclude?

Comment: @Bungo Oh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: The geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the dimension of $Kernel(\mathcal A - \lambda \mathcal Id)$. So we have that if $k \ne 0$ then $(x,y) \in Kernel(\mathcal A - 7 \mathcal Id) \iff (\mathcal A - 7 \mathcal Id)(x,y)=0 \iff y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

When $k \neq 0:$

A column vector that is **not** sent to zero by 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & k \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0  \\
1
\end{array}
\right),
$$
and
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & k \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0  \\
1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
k  \\
0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Putting the columns in reverse order, we get
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with
$$
P^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{k} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
after which
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{k} & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
7 & k \\
0 & 7
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
7 & 1 \\
0 & 7
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The point being that, as soon as $k \neq 0,$ the specific value of $k$ is not that important. The last matrix is the Jordan form of your original.